# Expressing a hyperplane as the span of several vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I express the hyperplane $x+y=1$ as the span of two vectors or more?

P. S. We have a 3D space.

Comment: The span of one or more vectors (in fact, zero or more vectors) always contains the origin. Your hyperplane does not. Do you mean something else?

Comment: You know, I'm reading Hidden Semi-Markov Model and in some where the article refer to projection of a vector G to a hyperplane using (MMT)G. M is the matrix of orthonormal base vectors of the hyperplane translated such that it crosses the origin of parameter space. I just can't figure out how make M :(

Comment: I mean : $(M*M^T)G$

Comment: @Arthur, How can I change the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only basic analytic geometry: find three different non-collinear points on the plane, for example

$$A=(1,0,1)\;,\;\;B=(1,0,0)\;,\;\;C=(0,1,0)$$

and now construct the directed vectors

$$\vec{AB}=B-A=(0,0,-1)\;,\;\;\vec{AC}=C-A=(-1,1,-1)$$

and then the plane is

$$\pi:\;A+r\vec{AB}+s\vec{AC}=(1,0,1)+r(0,0,-1)+s(-1,1,-1)\;,\;\;r,t\in\Bbb R$$

**Check**: take the vectorial product of the direction vectors to get a perpendicular vector to the plane:

$$\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}=\det\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\0&0&-1\\-1&1&-1\end{vmatrix}=(1,1,0)$$

and thus our plane is $\;x+y+d=0\;$ , and to find $\;d\;$ we can substitute any  point on the plane here, say $\;A\;$ , to obtain

$$0+0+d=0\implies d=0$$

and the wanted plane is

$$x+y-1=0$$

which, of course, it is the same as you give. This way is just a standard form to check that what we got at the beginning is correct.

Anyway, you can look at your plane as the translation of a *subspace*, so;

$$\pi:\;\;\text{Span}\,\left\{\;(0,0,-1)\,,\,\,(-1,1,-1)\;\right\}+(1,0,1)$$

Comment: Does $A$ on the plane? consider $x+y=1$

Comment: @mostafa8026 You're right, that's a minor typo. Correcting now

Comment: Thank you for correcting the answer, so Matrix of orthonormal base vectors of the hyperplane is: [0 -1;0 1; -1 -1]. right?

Comment: @mostafa8026 (1) As Arthur already commented, it may not be correct to talk of "base" when we don't even have a subspace, as in this case. What you can say is that your space is the translation of a subspace with basis those vectors. (2) And no: that basis is **not** an orthonormal one (at least with respect to the usual, standard inner product). It is just a "normal" basis.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. How can we translate M  such that it crosses the origin of parameter space?

Comment: I'm not sure what "parameter space" means, but if you want you can translate the whole hyperplane to a two dimensional subspace (and thus crossing the origin), by adding to your hyperplane the vector $\;(-1,0,-1)\;$ , which is just the additive inverse of the one shown in my answer at the end...

Comment: Why did you plus the span with $(1,0,1)$ in your answer? why not $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: @mostafa8026 I edited that. It is $\;A=(1,0,1)\;$

Comment: Could u please correct this too:
$$\pi:\;A+r\vec{AB}+s\vec{AC}=(0,0,1)+r(0,0,-1)+s(-1,1,-1)\;,\;\;r,t\in\Bbb R$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that it cannot be expressed as span of some vectors since the set of vectors satisfying the hyplerplane equation does not form a subspace. Nevertheless, let $u=\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ be any vector satisfying the equation $x+y=1$. Rearranging gives $y=1-x$ and substituting this into $u$ gives
\begin{align*}
u = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ 1-x \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + x\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that the OP said "hyperplane", not "line". It might be inconsequential, but it might also mean that this is to be done for an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Comment: consider 3D space please.

Comment: I was assuming the OP refers to 2D space, thanks for the correction thou!